# SparkSQL make a new column based on expression

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe called ipTraffic with the schema:

`ipTraffic: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ip: string, record_count: double]`

and I am trying to make a new column that takes the max value of column 
`"record_count"` and divides by the value of record count of that row.

I have run:

```
val calc = ipTraffic.agg(max("record_count")) / (ipTraffic("record_count"))
ipTraffic = ipTraffic.withColumn("weight", expr(calc))
```

and

```
val calc = ipTraffic.agg(max("record_count")).divide(ipTraffic("record_count"))
ipTraffic = ipTraffic.withColumn("weight", expr(calc))`
```

and gotten an error

```
error: value / is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

Which does not make sense to me since division is definitely in spark (obviously) but I went to https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/ and found it anyways and the "/" is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to divide a dataframe with a column:

```
ipTraffic.agg(max("record_count")):

+-----------------+
|max(record_count)| 
+-----------------+
|              3.0|
+-----------------+
```

divided by:

```
ipTraffic("record_count"):
+------------+
|record_count|
+------------+
|         1.0|
|         2.0|
|         3.0|
|         1.0|
|         2.0|
|         3.0|
+------------+
```

Instead, you can first calculate the max value, get it as literal value and then use it within your calculation:

```
import spark.implicits._     
val maxRecordCount = ipTraffic.agg(max($"record_count")).first.getDouble(0)
val ipTrafficWithWeight = ipTraffic.withColumn("weight", lit(maxRecordCount) / $"record_count")
```